# How to maintain <br/> tags in JSON?

Tags: javascript, regex, json, rss

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gcbx7L3o/

I'm getting a blog RSS feed in JSON format. I used `replace()` JS function to remove all the HTML tags inside the content since I only want it to be displayed in plain text format (without links, images, heading tags & etc).

I get stucked when I'm trying to maintain the `<br/>` tags. The `content` block have no break tags at all.

What is the correct regex should I use here?

===

Raw RSS: http://www.ohjob.info/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss

JSON RSS: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=2.0&q=http://www.ohjob.info/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss&num=1

===

My code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<button onclick="go()">Go</button>
<div id="title"></div>
<br>
<div id="post"></div>
<script>
function go() {
    var jsonobject = {
        "responseData": {
            "feed": {
                "feedUrl": "http://www.ohjob.info/feeds/posts/default?alt\u003drss",
                    "title": "Jawatan Kosong Kerajaan Dan Swasta 2014 | 2015",
                    "link": "http://www.ohjob.info/",
                    "author": "",
                    "description": "OhJobs, Jobs in Malaysia 2014, Jawatan Kosong 2014, Kerja Kosong 2014, Jawatan Kosong Kerajaan 2014, Jawatan Kosong Swasta 2014, Job Vacancy, Kerja Kosong Kerajaan, 2014, Iklan Jawatan Kosong 2014, Temuduga Terbuka 2014, Jawatan Kosong Kerajaan Terkini, Download Borang Jawatan Kosong, Kementerian Kesihatan, Majlis Bandaraya, Badan Berkanun, Majlis Perbandaran, Majlis Daerah, Universiti, Kolej, Jobsmalaysia, Kerajaan, Swasta, GLC, Job Vacancies",
                    "type": "rss20",
                    "entries": [{
                    "title": "Jawatan Kosong Perbadanan Kemajuan Pertanian Selangor (PKPS) (27 Oktober 2014)",
                        "link": "http://www.ohjob.info/2014/10/jawatan-kosong-perbadanan-kemajuan_9.html",
                        "author": "noreply@blogger.com (HambaAllah)",
                        "publishedDate": "Thu, 09 Oct 2014 19:49:00 -0700",
                        "contentSnippet": "Kerja Kosong Perbadanan Kemajuan Pertanian Selangor (PKPS)Permohonan adalah dipelawa kepada warganegara Malaysia bagi mengisi ...",
                        "content": "\u003cdiv style\u003d\"clear:both;text-align:center\"\u003e\u003ca href\u003d\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HSZLsHVqvQA/VDdITkJfeyI/AAAAAAAAQco/3dYT8K2UipE/s1600/Kerja%2BKosong%2BPerbadanan%2BKemajuan%2BPertanian%2BSelangor%2B(PKPS).jpg\" style\u003d\"clear:left;float:left;margin-bottom:1em;margin-right:1em\"\u003e\u003cimg alt\u003d\"Jawatan Kerja Kosong Perbadanan Kemajuan Pertanian Selangor (PKPS) logo www.ohjob.info oktober 2014\" border\u003d\"0\" src\u003d\"http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-HSZLsHVqvQA/VDdITkJfeyI/AAAAAAAAQco/3dYT8K2UipE/s1600/Kerja%2BKosong%2BPerbadanan%2BKemajuan%2BPertanian%2BSelangor%2B(PKPS).jpg\" height\u003d\"50\" width\u003d\"200\"\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cdiv style\u003d\"text-align:center\"\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003ca href\u003d\"http://www.ohjob.info/2012/09/iklan-disini.html\"\u003e\u003cu\u003eKerja Kosong\u003c/u\u003e\u003c/a\u003e Perbadanan Kemajuan Pertanian Selangor (PKPS)\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/div\u003ePermohonan adalah dipelawa kepada warganegara Malaysia bagi mengisi \u003ca href\u003d\"http://newjawatankosongkerajaan.blogspot.com/\"\u003e\u003cu\u003e\u003cb\u003ekekosongan jawatan\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/u\u003e\u003c/a\u003e di Perbadanan Kemajuan Pertanian Selangor (PKPS) seperti berikut:-\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e1\u003ca href\u003d\"http://newjawatankosongkerajaan.blogspot.com/\"\u003e.\u003c/a\u003e Pegawai Keselamatan (Security Officer)\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\"font-size:large\"\u003e\u003ca href\u003d\"http://www.pkps.gov.my/?p\u003d5820\" rel\u003d\"nofollow\"\u003e\u003cu\u003e\u003cb\u003eMUAT TURUN SYARAT KELAYAKAN\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/u\u003e\u003c/a\u003e\u003cbr\u003eDan cara memohon\u003c/span\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003eHubungi Kami:-\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003ePERBADANAN KEMAJUAN PERTANIAN SELANGOR\u003cbr\u003eWISMA PKPS\u003cbr\u003ePrecint 3.2, Tingkat 10 &ndash; 11,\u003cbr\u003ePersiaran Perbandaran, Seksyen 14,\u003cbr\u003e40000 Shah Alam, Selangor Darul Ehsan.\u003cbr\u003eTel : 03-55192621 / 2 / 3\u003cbr\u003eFax ; 03-55191481\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003eemail:   support@pkps.gov.my\u003cbr\u003e\u003cbr\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\"color:red\"\u003e\u003cb\u003e\u003cspan style\u003d\"font-size:x-large\"\u003eTarikh Tutup Permohonan:\u003ca href\u003d\"http://www.ohjob.info/\"\u003e-\u003c/a\u003e 27 Oktober 2014 \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/b\u003e\u003c/span\u003e",
                        "categories": [
                        "2014",
                        "Jawatan Kosong",
                        "Jawatan Kosong 2014",
                        "Jawatan Kosong Kerajaan",
                        "Jawatan Kosong Kerajaan 2014",
                        "Kerajaan",
                        "Kerja Kosong",
                        "Kerja Kosong 2014",
                        "kerja kosong kerajaan",
                        "Kerja Kosong Kerajaan 2014",
                        "Oktober",
                        "Selangor"]
                }]
            }
        },
            "responseDetails": null,
            "responseStatus": 200
    };

    // data
    var length = jsonobject.responseData.feed.entries.length;
    alert('Data length: ' + length);

    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    var titlestr = jsonobject.responseData.feed.entries[0].title;
    title.innerHTML = titlestr;

    var post = document.getElementById('post');
    var poststr = jsonobject.responseData.feed.entries[0].content.replace(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi, '');
    post.innerHTML = poststr;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead. Try `/<(?!br\s*\/?)[^>]+>/g`, like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjrfhat6/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regular expression.

Instead, just go ahead and insert the HTML, then iterate through and remove the elements that are not `BR`.

```
var poststr = jsonobject.responseData.feed.entries[0].content;

var els = post.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i = els.length; i--; ) {
    if (els[i].nodeName !== "BR") {
        unwrap(els[i]);
    }
}
```

---

Here's the `unwrap` function...

```
function unwrap(el) {
    while (el.childNodes[0]) {
        el.parentNode.insertBefore(el.childNodes[0], el);
    }
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
```

---

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/d4q6myme/

---

This gives you very fine-grained and reliable control over the elements that are inserted into the DOM without having to resort to the error-prone practice of using regex for this.

Comment: Thanks! This is new thing for me.

Comment: @zulhfreelancer: It's how a DOM is meant to be used. A regexp, except in the simplest cases, is the wrong tool.